# Performance of Property Get v Method

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class with a collection of methods in, and I was wondering if there is any performance bonus of using methods over properties?

Some of the methods are fairly complex, but basically return an IEnumerable collection of objects, while others are a simple `return values.Where(x => x.property == "comparison")` Linq query.

**Examples**

Method:

```
public IEnumerable<PenDataRow> ActivePens() => Pens.Where(x => x.Status == "Active");
```

Property:

```
public IEnumerable<PenDataRow> ActivePens => Pens.Where(x => x.Status == "Active");
```

Would it be better to mark them as properties or methods?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Properties are implemented as methods under the hood, so there is absolutely no performance difference. The [guidelines for choosing between a property and a method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054(v=vs.100)) are semantic.

Answer (score 4):

A property is just one or two methods with specific naming and metadata.

Therefore the overhead is the same, as are the opportunities for JIT inlining..

Answer (score 4):

There is no performance difference per se, but I would argue that users of your class might 'expect' one. That is, a property like `ActivePens` might be perceived to be 'lighter-weight' than a method like `GetActivePens()`. I try to write methods to get values of things that are more expensive. It's very subjective.

There may also be debugger-impact too - hovering over a property in a class in the debugger might call that property and incur an expensive operation to show you the tooltip.

Comment: Regarding the debugger impact, this is definitely true.  The debugger will attempt to evaluate properties when you hover over them, where it won't try to call methods by default.  This can have both ups and downs (harder to inspect if it's a method, but also won't cause unexpected side effects.)  The worst issue I ever encountered due to this was caused by a Singleton Instance where instantiating the Singleton caused side effects.  If you hit a breakpoint during its instantiation and hovered over Instance property, you could trigger an attempting re-instantiation, causing really weird results.

Comment: That said, it won't enumerate by default, so this specific case would not cause any unexpected overhead in the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, no performance gain whatsoever, because they are also methods that help expose your private fields, in a more elegant way.